# How to declare one custom module's dependency on another custom module

Tags: 8

I'm developing a set of site-specific custom modules, and one of them depends on the other one being enabled.

I'd like to declare this dependency in the `.info.yml` file, but [the docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/let-drupal-8-know-about-your-module-with-an-infoyml-file) only show how to declare dependencies on contrib projects:

> Dependencies should be namespaced in the format {project}:{module}, where {project} is the project name as it appears in the Drupal.org URL (e.g. drupal.org/project/views) and {module} is the module's machine name.

How do I declare a dependency on a module that is only found in the local codebase?

Comment: When creating the namespace of your custom module be sure to avoid those used by projects that are hosted at Drupal.org. As you may have noticed a single project download from Drupal.org may include a few modules. for example the 8.x Chaos tool suite (ctools) project contains three modules: Chaos tools, Chaos tools blocks (Experimental) and Chaos tools Views (Experimental). A dependency of ctools:ctools_block allows you to require the Chaos tools blocks module from within the project. You can also see this when requiring a module from core - drupal:views_ui

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this just like contrib projects.

```
dependencies:
  - your_module_name
```

Comment: If your project name and module name are the same you can use the shorthand as shown above.

Comment: With the addition of dependency namespacing, you should now use `your_module_name:your_module_name`

Answer (score 1):

Below is the more specific answer to load specifc library

```
dependencies:
  - <your_module_name>/<library_name>
```

Hope this gives an idea to load a specif library from the list of libraries in *.libraries.yml file